# How to aggregate two Strings and a List<byte[]> into a single byte[] and then extract them

Tags: java, android, sockets, io, arrays

I need to aggregate 2 Strings and a List into a single byte[] in order to send it through the network (using a special library that has a function send(byte[]).

Then, on the other end, I need to get the 3 different objects back.

I've done an ugly implementation of it, but it is very slow. Basically, what I do is

```
        public byte[] myserializer(String dataA, String dataB, List<byte[]> info) {

        byte[] header = (dataA +";" + dataB + ";").getBytes();

        int numOfBytes = 0;
        for (byte[] bs : info) {
            numOfBytes += bs.length;
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o;
        try {
            o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
            o.writeObject(info);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] data = b.toByteArray();

        int length = header.length + data.length;
        byte[] headerLength = (new Integer(header.length)).toString()
                .getBytes();
        byte[] pattern = ";".getBytes();
        int finalLength = headerLength.length + pattern.length + length;

        byte[] total = new byte[finalLength];enter code here
        total = // Copy headerLength, header and total into byte[] total

        return return;
```

In essence I'm creating kind of a frame that looks like this

```
      HEADER                    INFO
```

(-----------------------------------------------)(----------------------------------)
HEADER_LENGHT;DATA_A;DATA_B;SERIALIZED_LIST_OBJECT

Then, on the receiver side, I do the inverse process and that's "all". This works, but it is PRETTY inefficient and ugly.

Suggestions? Best practices? Ideas?

Oh...just one note more: this have to work for J2SE and Android too

Thanks so much in advanced!!

Comment: Probably, the serialization is a significant part of the performance cost.  So you may want to serialize the list yourself.  One obvious issue is delimiters between the byte arrays.  You could simplify this if there are any bytes you know will *not* be in the arrays.  Otherwise, you have to use some kind of escaping.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've trying to do, but it's kind of complex. I can't use any delimiters for the INFO chunk, because it can be binary data. I was thinking in adding the number of list elements and its length as part of the header... that way you don't need delimiters. 
I tried this approach but it ended in spaghetti code. 
The answer I picked, it tries to do this, but in a neater way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplistic method of serializing an array of bytes and deserialize it on the other side. Note that the method only accept one argument of type `List<byte[]>` and since your argument `dataA` and `dataB` are of type `String`, you can simply assume that the two first `byte[]` elements in the list are those two argument. I believe that this is a lot faster than object serialization through an `ObjectOutputStream` and will be faster to deserialize on the other side as well.

```
public class ByteListSerializer {
static private final int INT_SIZE = Integer.SIZE / 8;

    static public void main(String...args) {
        ByteListSerializer bls = new ByteListSerializer();

        // ============== variable declaration =================
        String dataA = "hello";
        String dataB = "world";
        List<byte[]> info = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        info.add(new byte[] {'s','o','m','e'});
        info.add(new byte[] {'d','a','t','a'});
        // ============= end variable declaration ==============

        // ======== serialization =========
        info.add(0, dataA.getBytes());
        info.add(1, dataB.getBytes());
        byte[] result = bls.dataSerializer(info);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

        // ======== deserialization ========
        List<byte[]> back = bls.dataDeserializer(result);

        String backDataA = new String(back.get(0));
        String backDataB = new String(back.get(1));
        back.remove(0);
        back.remove(0);

        // ============ print end result ============
        System.out.println(backDataA);
        System.out.println(backDataB);
        for (byte[] b : back) {
            System.out.println(new String(b));
        }
    }

    public byte[] dataSerializer(List<byte[]> data) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteBuffer lenBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);

        try {
            for (byte[] d : data) {
                lenBuffer.putInt(0, d.length);
                out.write(lenBuffer.array());
                out.write(d);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // wrap this
        byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[out.size() + 4];
        lenBuffer.putInt(0, out.size());
        System.arraycopy(lenBuffer.array(), 0, dataBuffer, 0, 4);
        System.arraycopy(out.toByteArray(), 0, dataBuffer, 4, out.size());

        return dataBuffer;
    }

    public List<byte[]> dataDeserializer(byte[] data) {
        if (data.length < INT_SIZE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("incomplete data");
        }

        ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
        int packetSize = dataBuffer.getInt();

        if (packetSize > data.length - INT_SIZE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("incomplete data");
        }

        List<byte[]> dataList = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        int len, pos = dataBuffer.position(), nextPos;

        while (dataBuffer.hasRemaining() && (packetSize > 0)) {
            len = dataBuffer.getInt();
            pos += INT_SIZE;
            nextPos = pos + len;
            dataList.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, pos, nextPos));

            dataBuffer.position(pos = nextPos);
            packetSize -= len;
        }

        return dataList;
    }
}
```

The frame is constructed as

```
     - 4 bytes: the total bytes to read (frame size = [nnnn] + 4 bytes header)
    |      - 4 bytes: the first chunk size in bytes
    |     |          - x bytes: the first chunk data
    |     |         |          
    |     |         |           - 4 bytes: the n chunk size in byte
    |     |         |          |         - x bytes: the n chunk data
    |     |         |          |        |
    |     |         |          |        |
[nnnn][iiii][dddd....][...][iiii][dddd...]
```

The example above will output

```
[0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0, 0, 5, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0, 0, 0, 5, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 0, 0, 0, 4, 115, 111, 109, 101, 0, 0, 0, 4, 100, 97, 116, 97]
hello
world
some
data
```

**Note** that the frame format is formed of `byte[]` chunks so as long as you know the order of the chunks, you can use these methods with virtually any set of data.

Comment: A `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` could do all that much more 'simplistically'.

Comment: @EJP, I believe it will result in just about the same code as `DataOutputStream` does not "serialize" but simply output data as bytes (like in my example), and you still have to prepend the 4 bytes frame length before returning the resulting bytes.

Comment: Just a question: how in/efficient is ByteArrayOutputStream and ByteBuffer objects? Think that I create one instance of each per frame I send.

Comment: depends how often you are calling the methods. Object creation is usually cost effective, but having a class level instance will cause your class to be NOT thread safe. If you know for sure that your class will not have concurrent access, you can have a single instance of `ByteBuffer` and reuse `ByteArrayOutputStream` using `ByteArrayOutputStream.reset()` to reinitialize it. If you class will have concurrent access, you could have a synchronized pool of these objects... but this is going out of the question scope. I suggest you test as it is and improve if speed becomes more critical.

Answer (score 2):

Write it all to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, with an ObjectOutputStream around it to serialize the Strings and the List, and then call the method that turns the BAOS into a byte[] array. At the other end, do the inverse.

Or define a serializable object that contains the `{String, String, List}` tuple and just serialize that with `ObjectOutputStream`, and deserialize that with `ObjectInputStream`. Much simpler.

Or just do three sends. TCP is a byte stream, there are no boundaries between the messages, the bytes all arrive sequentially. If you want to conserve writes to the network, interpose a `BufferedOutputStream` and flush it after writing the `List`.

Comment: wrapping the parameters inside an internal object would be more flexible and easier to maintain